# How to raise error for email field if user is trying to pass just few letters

Tags: python, django, validation

How can I rise the error and information, if user is puting only "dummy date" without "@"?
Email model is `email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)` but is only preventing passsing empty field, and nothing else. Can someone advice ?

```
def addContact(request):
    form = ContactForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/contact')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'contact/new.html', context)
```

Forms:

```
class ContactForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = '__all__'
```

Models:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    relationship = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name
```

Comment: can you paste `ContactForm`, please?

Comment: and the model, please?

Comment: @PawełKordowski

Comment: `EmailField` should do the validation you want, what is in `contact/new.html`?

Comment: the check is done on backend site so the user is able to post incorrect data but it won't pass the backend validation

Comment: @af af thak you for docs but im too noob to be able to do it by myself. Can you guys help me a bit more ? thanks a lot ;)

Comment: Is it this one ? If it is where should I paste it ?

def __call__(self, value):
        if not value or '@' not in value:
            raise ValidationError(self.message, code=self.code)

Answer (score 0):

If you use EmailField then it has a built-in validator. Here is the code (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/validators/#emailvalidator)

You can use this validator to check the user input.

Here is the source code: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/core/validators/#EmailValidator